# Calculate difference from previous date in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table like below. In this table, the "model" column contains file type information.

We log the latest updated date of any file Type(AFP/Arch/ etc..) along with the date of the day that we are inputting these values.

For example, if I'm inputting the values today and I found that the file AFP is updated yesterday. The row would be like

```
|File type|   |Date of Input|    |updated date|
|  AFP    |   |  2018.05.09 |    | 2018.05.08 |
```

[image: Date update table]

Using this I would like to create a pivot table that shows me the Difference of the column "Update" from the Previous "Date". The desired values in the above example would be "1"(the difference between today & yesterday). But using the show value as "Difference from" option doesn't give me proper values with dates.

Please, find the date below.

[image: excel image]

```
| Model         | Date       | Update     |   |   |
|---------------|------------|------------|---|---|
| AFP           | 2018.03.05 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| AFP           | 2018.03.07 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| AFP           | 2018.03.09 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| AFP           | 2018.03.14 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| AFP_FP        | 2018.03.07 | 2018.03.06 |   |   |
| AFP_FP        | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| AFP_FP        | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| Arch          | 2018.03.05 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| Arch          | 2018.03.07 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| Arch          | 2018.03.09 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| Arch          | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.13 |   |   |
| EL            | 2018.03.05 | 2018.03.01 |   |   |
| EL            | 2018.03.07 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| EL            | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| EL            | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| PO HD         | 2018.03.05 | 2018.03.02 |   |   |
| PO HD         | 2018.03.07 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| PO HD         | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| PO HD         | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.14 |   |   |
| PO HP         | 2018.03.05 | 2018.03.02 |   |   |
| PO HP         | 2018.03.07 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| PO HP         | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| PO HP         | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.14 |   |   |
| PO PL         | 2018.03.05 | 2018.03.02 |   |   |
| PO PL         | 2018.03.07 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| PO PL         | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.09 |   |   |
| PO PL         | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.14 |   |   |
| RCP           | 2018.03.05 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| RCP           | 2018.03.07 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| RCP           | 2018.03.09 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| RCP           | 2018.03.14 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| SPW()         | 2018.03.05 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| SPW()         | 2018.03.07 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| SPW()         | 2018.03.09 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| SPW()         | 2018.03.14 | 2018.02.26 |   |   |
| STR           | 2018.03.05 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| STR           | 2018.03.07 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| STR           | 2018.03.09 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| STR           | 2018.03.14 | 2018.02.22 |   |   |
| STR - Patriot | 2018.03.09 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| STR - Patriot | 2018.03.14 | 2018.03.07 |   |   |
| TD PL         | 2018.03.05 | 2017.07.11 |   |   |
| TD PL         | 2018.03.07 | 2017.07.11 |   |   |
| TD PL         | 2018.03.09 | 2017.07.11 |   |   |
| TD PL         | 2018.03.14 | 2017.07.11 |   |   |
```

Comment: Could you just talk us through one example, let's say AFP, and explain how the desired result is arrived at?

Comment: And please include some data perhaps using something like an [online table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so people can copy paste your data to work with. And explain how the two tables are related as the Date/Update pairs don't correspond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dragging **Model** pill to rows and **Date** Pill to Columns (which seems that you have done this already), you should drag the **Update** to values, summarize it by Sum and Show Value as **Difference From** with base fields **Date** and Base item **previous**

The final screenshot is as follows. Only that your desired value for **14.03.2018 X Arch** is 21, my calculation is 19:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Or you could do it the hard way with a calculated field! Nice solution!