# Calculating the Difference in Dates in Excel, and Pivot Tables

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to do the same thing(ish), as in another question, but I'm perplexed by the answer as it doesn't add up for me. It might help if you see this referenced question ([Calculate difference from previous date in Excel pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247589/calculate-difference-from-previous-date-in-excel-pivot-table/59738528#59738528)). Why is it that in this solution example does the difference in dates show up as 43165 ("days"—I'm assuming)? My model is working to show days between subscription start dates and end dates. So it's should be pretty much the same thing.

Further more, I don't understand why it is when I do a date difference calculation inside the excel table that it works, but when I use it as a calculated field in a pivot table it doesn't work. This is the Formula I used. =ABS(MONTH(J2)-MONTH(D2))+1

I used Absolute because it was showing negatives. I added 1 month to account for the current month and because subs showing less than 30 days, would display 0(zero) months.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Very hard to answer without seeing some data.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the link I provided would help. How's this link? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTxpa.png